# Working with python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a function that takes in an argument.  From that argument, I want to compare it to a dictionary's set of keys and return the key's value for any matches.  So far I have been able to only return the argument matches for the keys.

```
def func(str):
  a = []
  b = {'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}
  for i in str:
    if i in b.keys():
      a.append(i)
  return a
```

Output sample:

func('abcdefghiabcdefghi')

['a','c','e','a','c','e']

Wanted output:

['b','d','f','b','d','f']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best not to use `str` as  a variable name. I think your function can be written more simply  like this

```
def func(mystr):
  b = {'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}
  return [b[k] for k in mystr if k in b]
```

If you don't want to use a list comprehension, then you can fix it like this

```
def func(mystr):
  a = []
  b = {'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}
  for i in mystr:
    if i in b:           # i in b works the same as i in b.keys()
      a.append(b[i])     # look up the key(i) in the dictionary(b) here
  return a
```

Comment: Thanks, Where is the reference to use the value in the return though?  It works fine, I just want to understand. EDIT:  Oh , this was silly of me , just by calling on the key it returns the value.

Comment: You get the value by using the key as an index. That's kind of what dicts are **for**.

Comment: Hey Karl, I didn't even get to see your comment before I edited mine.  Up in the sample function I posted, I was thinking that in order to look up arguments and return either keys or values, I had to use the .values() or .keys() method.  Thanks for the response.